Shape mismatch. The variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512), and the assigned value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible
I'm running this code and I have adjusted as shown below:
import requests
//first block
import requests
url = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
response = requests.get(url)
with open('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

//second block
def create_model(input_shape, n_out):
    input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape)
    base_model = applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', 
                                       include_top=False,
                                       input_tensor=input_tensor)
    base_model.load_weights('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

    `x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)`
    `x = Dropout(0.5)(x)`
    `x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)`
    `x = Dropout(0.5)(x)`
    `final_output = Dense(n_out, activation='softmax', name='final_output')(x)`
    `model = Model(input_tensor, final_output)`
    
    return model

//third block
model = create_model(input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CANAL), n_out=N_CLASSES)

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

for i in range(-5, 0):
    model.layers[i].trainable = True

`metric_list = ["accuracy"]`
`optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=WARMUP_LEARNING_RATE)`
`model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy",  metrics=metric_list)`
`model.summary()`


However, when I run the 3rd block, I got an error:
ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512), and the assigned value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible.

I tried changing my weights from
weights='None'
to:
weights='imagenet'
But I'm still having this error, could anyone perhaps know why?

What is the input shape you are creating here?

@darthbaba HEIGHT = 224
WIDTH = 224
CANAL = 3
